# CAS OAuth Integrating Using Google

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas, google-oauth

I have configured CAS 3.5.2 server to have OAuth Client support, I have successfully done authentication using Facebook now I want to extend it to have Google support as well, I am doing the same thing I did for Facebook i.e providing client ID and Secret but I am getting this error

```
 <Failed to get user data, code : 404 / body : <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/api/people/@me/@self</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

If anyone can point me to right direction I would be immensely thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the OAuth support for CAS.

Google has removed its support for OAuth protocol version 1.0 and therefore GoogleProvider does not work any more.

You should upgrade to :

- Google2Provider (use scribe-up 1.3.1 dependency instead of scribe-up 1.2.0 if you use CAS server 3.5.2)
- Google2Client (use pac4j-oauth 1.4.0 dependency if you use CAS server 4.0.0).